# MySQL: get last order, first order and order amount per customer

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 tables, one is "Customer", and the second is "Order".
Columns in Customer are:
customer_id
fname
lname
email

Columns in Order are:
order_id
customer_id
date
amount

I need to run a query to get for each customer their first order, last order and their amount (and details for each customer)

To get first order and last order per customer, that's my solution:

```
select fname
     , lname
     , email
     , max(date)
     , min(date)
from customer c
join order o
on c.customer_id = o.customer_id
group 
    by c.customer_id;
```

However, I'm not really sure how to get their amount too, since if I add amount, since the results are wrong if I do that. Should I use a different solution?

Thanks

Comment: `order` is a reserved word in MySQL. For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select *
from customers c
inner join (
    select o.*,
        row_number() over(partition by customer_id order by date) as rn_asc,
        row_number() over(partition by customer_id order by date desc) as rn_desc
    from orders o
) o on o.customer_id = c.customer_id 
where 1 in (o.rn_asc, o.rn_desc)
```

This generates two rows per customer, with the earlierst and latest order.

If you want one row per customer only, then you can aggregate in the outer query:

```
select c.*, 
    min(o.date) as first_order_date, 
    max(case when rn_asc = 1  then o.amount end) as first_order_amount,
    max(o.date) as last_order_date, 
    max(case when rn_desc = 1 then o.amount end) as last_order_amount   
from customers c
inner join (
    select o.*,
        row_number() over(partition by customer_id order by date) as rn_asc,
        row_number() over(partition by customer_id order by date desc) as rn_desc
    from orders o
) o on o.customer_id = c.customer_id 
where 1 in (o.rn_asc, o.rn_desc)
group by c.customer_id
```

Answer (score -1):

One method is to use `row_number()` to enumerate the orders and then use conditional aggregation:

```
select c.fname, c.lname, c.email, max(o.date), min(o.date),
       max(case when seqnum_asc = 1 then amount end) as first_order_amount,
       max(case when seqnum_desc = 1 then amount end) as last_order_amount,
from customer c join
     (select o.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by date asc) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by date desc) as seqnum_desc
      from order o
     ) o
     on c.customer_id = o.customer_id
group by c.customer_id
```